# Please explain the strange lifetime of variables in this makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

The echo in my rule for `all` prints out the proper thing, but the makefile does not work when I move the definition of OBJS to the line I commented. As is, the makefile runs, but when I move OBJS I get the following error:

> user@machine$ make 
>   OBJS = other.o main.o 
>   g++ -Wall other.o main.o -o main 
>   g++: error: other.o: No such file or directory
>   g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory

```
#MAKEFILE

CPP_COMP=g++

CFLAGS = -Wall

CPP_SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp) 

#Define OBJS here and the makefile works. Define OBJS *HERE* it fails as shown below.
OBJS = $(CPP_SRC:.cpp=.o)

all: $(OBJS) 
        @echo "OBJS = $(OBJS)"
        $(CPP_COMP) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o main

#*HERE*
#Why can't I put CPP_SRC and OBJS here?
#The echo statement above prints out the appropriate value even if I put the variables here.

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CPP_COMP) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
        rm *.o main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makefile variables set with `=` (as opposed to `:=`) are NOT evaluated and expanded when they are set, only when they are used.  Variables used in a rule are expanded when the rule is defined (to determine what the targets and prerequisites are), but variables used in an action are not expanded until the action is actually *run*.

So in your example, setting `OBJS = $(CPP_SRC:.cpp=.o)` sets `OBJS` to that actual string (with a `$` and everything).  Then when you have the rule `all: $(OBJS)`, at that point, it expands `$(OBJS)` which in turn expands `$(CPP_SRC)`, and then runs the `$(wildcard`... command.  On the other hand, the action `@echo "OBJS = $(OBJS)"` again just records that string with no expansion.  Only when the action actually runs (which happens after then entire Makefile is read and it starts figuring out what to run) is `$(OBJS)` expanded.

So moving down the definition of `OBJS` means that it is not yet defined when the rule is read (so it expands to an empty string), but is defined when the action is run.

Comment: As Spicer would add: **period**. :-)